# Can VS Code's runSelectedText source a function or strip parts of the command before execution?

Tags: visual-studio-code, openfoam

I use Visual Studio Code to write and execute OpenFOAM scripts. To avoid copying and pasting commands when creating a script, I use a keyboard shortcut to run selected text (`workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText`). In OpenFOAM scripts, commands are commonly preceded by a run-function (`runApplication` and `runParallel`). Within scripts, these functions are sourced with `. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/tools/RunFunctions`. OpenFOAM commands prefixed with a run-function generate a log-file at script execution, and in case of `runParallel`, also assemble the `mpirun` command. Unfortunately, these run-functions are not understood by the terminal. Therefore, the execution of multiple lines is not easily possible.

How can I either include the run-functions, or remove `runApplication` or `runParallel` with all their options (`-append`, `-overwrite`, etc.) on every `runSelectedText` input?

If you have OpenFOAM, you can use the windAroundBuildings tutorial (`$FOAM_TUTORIALS/incompressible/simpleFoam/windAroundBuildings/`) as MWE; its `./Allrun` script reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ${0%/*} || exit 1    # run from this directory

# Source tutorial run functions
. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/tools/RunFunctions

runApplication surfaceFeatures

runApplication blockMesh
runApplication snappyHexMesh -overwrite

runApplication $(getApplication)
```

How can I execute the following lines from the above script with my `runSelectedText` keyboard shortcut? Preferably, all three lines should be executed at once.

```
runApplication surfaceFeatures
runApplication blockMesh
runApplication snappyHexMesh -overwrite
```

Comment: What is the error message shown when you try to run runApplication?

Comment: The terminal answers with `bash: runApplication: command not found`.

Comment: @fdireito I can solve my issue by sourcing `. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/tools/RunFunctions` in the `.bashrc` file. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Or in your own script, as it is done in the Allrun you showed.